# Freeswitch ipv6 call is not working

Tags: ipv6, freeswitch

User is connected to an ipv6 network. SIP registration is fine . But when i make call to that user from freeswitch commandline(fs_cli) it is showing error as  Cannot create outgoing channel of type [error] cause: [USER_NOT_REGISTERED].it is only looking in ip4 profile .it is not looking in internal-ipv6 profile

Comment: Can you post the logs from the call and the relevant portion of your dialplan?